# House number 1 or One in address?

Tags: numbers, style-manuals

I noticed that some companies and institutions write the house number 1 as One, and some institutions write 1.

> [One Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA 95014, USA](https://www.apple.com/retail/infiniteloop/)
> [One Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052, USA](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Investor/contact-information.aspx)
> [One University Avenue, Mechanicsburg, PA 17055, USA](https://www.messiah.edu/)
> [1 University Heights, Asheville, NC 28804, USA](https://www.unca.edu/)
> [1 University Gardens, Glasgow, G12 8QQ, UK](https://universitystory.gla.ac.uk/building/?id=93)

Is it a matter of style?
Why does this thing only exist for addresses with house number 1? Is it because the 1 is not obvious as One?

Comment: I’d imagine it could be done with any number if they wanted to. Two, Five, Ten, Fifteen Hundred…

Comment: Not just 1. In Cambridge UK, 101 Science Park is labelled [one zero one](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@52.2327116,0.148967,3a,75y,48.84h,82.22t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1snO3f-0lT5Rcj-vaxI_r5QQ!2e0!7i16384!8i8192). And in Birmingham UK, there is "one zero one The Studio" at the Unit 101 Jubilee Trade Centre.

Comment: You could justify it in practical terms - a one written as a single stroke is easy to miss or confuse. But usually it is style more than function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally numbers less than one hundred are spelled out in proper English, though this limit may vary. House number are normally written as Arabic numerals since that is how they are presented on each house or building. Such vanity addresses are typically written as O-N- E Celebrity Drive or else what is the point.

Comment: This is normal where? Not in the UK, where it's usual to use numerals. I know the US has a different convention for house numbering, involving much larger numbers.

Comment: According to a conversation I had with my local letter carrier (and therefore this is anecdotal, not verified), the United States Post Office only requires that the address be UNAMBIGUOUS - but if it's not written in standard form, any delays in delivery are your problem, not the USPS's (i.e., guarantees of timeliness for Express Mail or Priority Mail are not in effect). Generally, in the NYC area, only well-known locations or vanity addresses use non-numeric addressing, and a few are recognized with no number at all (e.g., Grand Central Terminal, many of the museums, City Hall).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin in UK many (residential) addresses don't even have a number, just a name. The postcode (zip code) narrows it down to just a few properties anyway.

Comment: @WeatherVane - oh, yes, different countries will definitely have different rules and conventions; I did some (superficial) research on this for some SF world-building ideas, and wrote up my findings at https://www.freelancetraveller.com/features/preproom/jottings/addresses.html - there are quite a number of ways to specify an address...